# Jenkins build failure with maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am having trouble compiling and packaging an application (jar) with Maven through a Jenkins build since I have dependency that is not available through artifactory. The dependecy is installed on remote servers at a specific location. Is it possible to compile and build my app so that I can deploy it to the remote servers where it will then reference the dependent jar?

FYI, for my local development I installed the jar into my local repo.

Comment: Have you checked advice in -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188998/maven-cant-find-artifacts-in-remote-file-repository/56267978#56267978

Answer (score 0):

You should be able upload the 3rd party jar into artifactory which would then allow jenkins to access it during the build

https://www.theserverside.com/video/4-ways-to-upload-a-JAR-to-a-JFrog-Artifactory-repository

Comment: licensing prevents me from uploading to artifactory.